# Can't open a pointed url of selected objects

Tags: javascript, three.js, raycasting, tween

I am trying to navigate to the concerned link when clicking on the concerned planets using raycaster. Instead, it takes me to the URL of the last planet (here called category) when clicking on any part of the canvas. I am using a function to create the planets and tween separately from init(). How do I structure raycaster to click only on planets in order to navigate to their concerned URL. Thanks for your time.

Code below:

```
class App extends Component{

  componentDidMount() {
    var scene, camera, renderer;
    var controls;
    var category, orbit, orbitContainer

    init();
    animate();

    function createSubCategory(){}

    function createCategory(name, radius, distance, tilt, color, speed, link) {
      orbitContainer = new THREE.Object3D();
      orbitContainer.rotation.x = tilt;
      //  orbitContainer.rotation.x = 700;

         var id = name

        orbit = new THREE.Object3D();

        var geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(distance, 100);
        geometry.vertices.shift();
        var line = new THREE.Line(
          geometry,
           new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 'aqua'})
        );

        //ring movement
        line.rotation.x = Math.PI * 0.5;

        category = new THREE.Mesh(
          new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, 0, 0),
            //new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:color,wireframe: true})
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:color,wireframe: true})
        );
        orbitContainer.userData.URL= link
        // initial position
        // distance away from the center

        //change initial position

        category.position.set(distance, 0.0, 0.0);

        //orbit.add(line);
        orbit.add(category);

        new TWEEN.Tween(orbit.rotation,{
          loop: true,

          //useTicks: true,
          //css: true,
          //ignoreGlobalPause: true
      }).to({y:  //'+' or '-' for rotation direction
        '+' + (Math.PI * 2)}, 4000 / speed);





        orbitContainer.add(orbit);
        scene.add(orbitContainer);


    }

    function init() {

        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x202020);

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, 4 / 3, 0.1, 10000.0);
        camera.position.set(20.0, 20.0, 20.0);
        camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: false});
       document.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);
        controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

        var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.1);
        scene.add(ambientLight);

//light emission will be the icon with a line connecting to the logo (sun) and will light up the line and icon when selected 

        var solar = new THREE.Mesh(
            new THREE.SphereGeometry(2.5, 32, 32),
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({emissive: 0xff5800, emissiveIntensity: 0.5, wireframe: true, color:'silver'})
        );

        var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1.0, 300.0);
        solar.add(pointLight);
        scene.add(solar);

        createCategory('B',1.35, 7.2, 0.0, 'yellow', 0.4, "http://google.com" );
        createCategory('A',1.35, 11.0, 0.0, 'red', 0.3, "http://yahoo.com");
        createCategory('D Print', 1.35, 14.0, 0.0, 'blue', 0.2, "http://msn.com");
        createCategory('C Design', 1.35, 17.3, 0.0, 'green', 0.1, "http://facebook.com");
        createCategory('N', 1.35, 12.2, 5.0, 'pink', 0.4, "http://stackoverflow.com");

        window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
        onWindowResize();

        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    }
    function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
      event.preventDefault();


          var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(); // create once
          var mouse = new THREE.Vector2(); // create once
          mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
          mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;
          raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

          var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(orbitContainer);
      if (intersects.length === 0) {
          window.open(orbitContainer.userData.URL);
      }
  }
    function onWindowResize() {
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    }

    function animate() {

        controls.update();

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems with your code:

#### Problem 1:

> it takes me to the URL of the last planet

This is because you're using the same global variable `orbitContainer` to create 5 categories. Each time you call `createCategory`, the URL gets overwritten, so when you call `window.open(orbitContainer.userData.URL);`, it's opening the last one you assigned. What's happening is something like this:

```
orbitContainer.userData.URL = "http://google.com";
orbitContainer.userData.URL = "http://yahoo.com";
orbitContainer.userData.URL = "http://msn.com";
orbitContainer.userData.URL = "http://facebook.com";
orbitContainer.userData.URL = "http://stackoverflow.com";

window.open(orbitContainer.userData.URL); // <- this opens stackoverflow
```

*Solution:* you should get the URL from the result of the raycaster:

```
intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );

if (intersects.length > 0) {
    window.open(intersects[0].object.userData.URL);
}
```

#### Problem 2:

> when clicking on any part of the canvas

this is because you're explicitly checking for zero intersections when you do this:

```
if (intersects.length === 0) {
    window.open(orbitContainer.userData.URL);
}
```

you should be checking for interceptions with `if (intersects.length > 0)` as demonstrated in the solution above.

Also, make sure you're performing a raycaster with the scene's children: `raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );` not with `orbitContainer`, because as I said, you overwrite it each time you create a new category, and it won't have all objects inside of it.

Comment: Hey marquizzo, thanks for your answer, I will definitely get back to you tomorrow, when I get back to this issue, I tried the exact solution it opens a blank page when clicking on the solar but that's it. Thought I will dive deeper into it when I have time and get back to you

Comment: your solution is not working unfortunately, it just allows you to click on the solar object and it opens a blank tab. No categories are responsive to clicks and none of the URLs open up. Would you mind that we use Skype or Teamviewer to sort this out if that's okay?

Comment: No, I'm not interested in using Skype for personal consultation. Why don't you just use `console.log(intersects)` and start digging through the array in the console? There you'll find all the information of of the object you're clicking on, including the`userData` you created. Best of luck!